# Missing vector features when import from .sqlite to postgis?

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, vector, database

I imported vector data from a .sqlite file to PostGIS but not all of my vector features imported.

I haven't been able to determine a reason for most of the loss of features between the databases (being potentially erroneous attribution or lack of xy coordinates).

Why am I missing vector features in my database after the import from .sqlite file?

[image]

an example, the building layer with 78 features, the 2 features which do not migrate are pointID 221 and 262 being addressed 17896 buckhorn and 56430 buckhorn

[image]

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Perhaps you could identify the missing features and post them? Are there any errors?